# Switch audio seamlessly with HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I have two different variants of the same file (e.g. coded with different codecs) and I would like to play both with two buttons. I manage to switch between the two files, however there is a gap when switching which I would like to avoid. Is there any good method to avoid this gap while switching between the two wave files?

Here is the way it's currently implemented:

```
            this[id+kbps].volume = vol;
            this[id+kbps].currentTime = this[actualFile+kbits].currentTime;
            this[actualFile+kbps].pause();
            this[id+kbps].addEventListener('ended', function() {
                this.currentTime = 0;
                this.play();
            }, false);
            this[id+kbps].play();
            actualFile = id;
```

Comment: is `this` and `<audio>` element? if so - could you try the switch on the `paused` event? or maybe have 2 `<audio>` tags (one for each file) and just play/pause between the 2 to test delays?